# Как отслеживать перезагрузку страницы Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Мне нужна ваша помощь. В моем приложении есть необходимость отслеживать перезагрузку страницы и сколько раз она была перезагружена. В Angular у нас есть HostListener, который помогает отслеживать события в Angular приложении. Например, у меня есть 2 переменные: `isPageReloaded: boolean` и `countTimesPageReloaded: number`. Первая переменная для простой проверки была ли перезагружена страница, а вторая для количества перезагрузок. Помогите пожалуста: Как можно выполнить эту проверку и записывать данные? Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0):

Если для конкретного пользователя, то можно повесить обработчик на страницу, который будет итерировать каждый раз число в куку. И брать оттуда данные. А при переходе на другую страницу зачищать ее.